# Laravel Routing with alias

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm newbie at Laravel,

I'm using Laravel 5 and i've created alias for it (laravel.dev).

I'm having

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

error while i browse http://localhost/laravel.dev/Register

i've created following routing

```
Route::get('Register','SiteController@Register');
```

here is my controller file code

```
public function Register(){
    return 'Register';
}
```

this is .htaccess file of public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

this is my alias file

```
Alias /laravel.dev/ "C:\wamp\www\Laravel\public/" 

<Directory "C:\wamp\www\Laravel\public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: i'm using `php artisan serve` for now and it working perfectly

Comment: Interesting topic. Have you tried this : http://laravel.io/forum/12-05-2014-route-aliases ?

Comment: nop, where exactly i write those codes (don't mind, i'm pretty new to laravel )

Comment: @zlen its totally NOT about laravel. its about virtual host aliasing